# Are AVL&RB Trees without additional storage for balance information in each node feasible?

Tags: binary-trees, balanced-search-trees, avl-trees, red-black-trees

One advantage claimed for [scapegoat trees](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapegoat_tree) over other balanced trees like [AVL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) or [red-black](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)(RB trees - just mentioning AVL henceforth) is not needing to store additional balance information.
But can't an [AVL tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) node do without additional storage for balance information?
(I'm not considering possibilities to hide it in "the payload" (*item*, considered "immutable for the tree handling").)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One frequent characterisation of the storage for the balance information for an *AVL tree node* (henceforth *node*) is *2 bits*:
either for *balance factors* (differences between children's heights) of -1, 0, or 1,
or *leftIsTaller*&*rightIsTaller*.

More than half the nodes being leaves, it is possible to reduce this to one bit:
The balance of nodes with less than two children is obvious; for two children, *push down the bits left&right*.

Customarily, AVL trees are described (&implemented) with targeted access to each child as *left* or *right* child.
Keeping that, it should be possible to encode one bit in either having the children in their proper place as implied by *key order*, or exchanged.
There would seem to be a problem with leaves, but those can be detected to be leaves in constant time, the parent leaning their way if there is no sibling; the sibling's way if that is not a leaf.

(The implementation for "0-overhead (balanced) trees" haunting me being
two *maps* from *parent item* to *left child item* and right.)

Comment: `targeted access to each child` customarily, "we" think *ordered* tree without mention.

Comment: More useful questions may include: **What**, usually, is "stored in that bit"? Well, the result of *comparing left* to *right*. **When** is it useful to store the (non-local) balance information instead of *order*? Whenever in the use of the tree this promises to reduce cost. Even analysing just look-up cost, the effects of different representations are hard to assess.

Comment: Accept your own answer otherwise it will keep popping forever looking for an answer.

Comment: (@AlokMaity: never noticed, the one tag I'm watching is [tag:algorithms].)